# jquery variable not defined

Tags: jquery, variables, jsonp

I'm getting an uncaught referenceError whenever the 'countryDetail' function calls the 'country' variable using the following code:

```
function load_countries(e) {
var count = e.features.length;      
if (!count) {return;}   
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var feature = e.features[i];
    // get the country name & rank
    country = feature.data.properties.NAME
    score = rsfpfi2010[country]

    feature.element.setAttribute("onmouseover", "countryDetail("+country+","+score+");");
        feature.element.setAttribute("onmouseout", "hideCountryDetail();");
    feature.element.onmousemove = detailFollow;
}
}

// Tooltip content & display
function countryDetail(c,s) {
//console.log(c,s);
if (score == undefined) {
    $("#tooltip").html("<h3>"+ c +"</h3><br/>Data Unavailable");
} else {
    $("#tooltip").html("<h3>"+ c +"</h3><br/>Score: " + s);
}
$("#tooltip").show();
}
```

What I don't understand is that if I replace 'country' with 'score', like in the following line:

```
feature.element.setAttribute("onmouseover", "countryDetail("+score+","+score+");");
```

everything runs fine. (Except I don't get the data I need, of course).

The 'score' variable is called from a json file loaded in the header, whereas the 'country' variable is pulled directly from geoJSON data written to the page.

I'm almost positive i've missed something dead simple but by now i'm totally bind to it.

thanks in advance!
Nathan

Comment: Have you tried alerting `feature.data.properties.NAME` to make sure it contains what you think it does? The obvious answer is that you've got your case wrong, or something is meaning that exact variable name doesn't exist, hence the undefined.

Comment: In addition to @Joe's suggestion, stop it with the bad habit of forgetting semicolons. JavaScript is a forgetting language, but do not abuse it. Also, inside your `countryDetail` function you are checking `score == undefined`, but the variable `score` does not exist in that function's scope, it will definitely complain about it.

Comment: If you started using jQuery - use it everywhere :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
$(feature.element).hover(function () {
    countryDetail(country, score);
}, function () {
    hideCountryDetail();
}).move(detailFollow);
```

instead of

```
feature.element.setAttribute("onmouseover", "countryDetail("+country+","+score+");");
    feature.element.setAttribute("onmouseout", "hideCountryDetail();");
feature.element.onmousemove = detailFollow;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I got it working by adding the data as attributes to the svg paths & then using the JQuery suggested by @Samich. Not sure if it's the best way to do it, but it's working as it should now. Also cleaned up the Jquery, as suggested. Code below in case someone needs it later